# Can't view database objects in SQL 2008 Database Project within Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I've created a SQL 2008 database project in Visual Studio 2010. I have imported existing tables and stored procedures using both of the available methods of import (script or connecting to db). Regardless of which method I use, after the import completes I see my table files in the Visual Studio project, however, I get the following error when trying to view the object by double clicking on it:

***Object reference not set to an instance of an object.***

I can also see the files I am trying to access on the hard drive. Perhaps this is a permissions issue masked with an obscure error message? I've done some research and am stumped at this point. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Details on Visual Studio 2010: Version 10.0.40291.1 SP1Rel

My OS is: Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Starting VS 2010 with "devenv /ResetSkipPkgs", should help, mostly due to the "non-loading problem" of some of the key modules.